# ReactJS simple form wizard

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, reactjs, redux

For learning purpose I am writing a small app with a wizard in ReactJS.

I have created some components for the wizard as follow;

- ProgressBar
- Wizard

  - WizardStepOne
  - WizardStepOneForm
  - WizardStepTwo
  - WizardStepTwoForm

In the wizard component I have included my PorgressBar compnent for showing progression and created a switch statement to determine the oneClick value of the button included in each 'StepForm' to get a value and showing the next 'WizardStepTwoForm' component.

This all works well and does exactly what I expect but I am facing one problem. I don't want the user is able to get the next 'WizardStepTwoForm' form before I have validated the 'WizardStepOneForm'. So some how I should return a status to my parent component to determine if the user can click to the next state. Or, I disable the button by a state till a validation has been done but in this case the user won't be able to click on the button for an validation of the form.

During the submission of the form I want to send the data to the API, the dispatch is working but I am just wondering how to work it out right so my switch statement in the parent(Wizard) will only be fired if the form is valid.

**Wizard**

```
//.. imports

class Wizard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            step : 'stepOne',
            progression : '0%'
        };

        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const wizard = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('wizard'));
        if (wizard !== null) {
            this.setState({
                step: wizard.step,
                progression: wizard.progression
            });
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        localStorage.setItem('wizard', JSON.stringify({
            step        : this.state.step,
            progression : this.state.progression
        }));
    }

    handleFormSubmit(e) {

        switch (e.target.value) {
            case 'stepOne' :
                this.setState({
                    step : 'stepOne',
                    progression : '0%',
                });
                break;
            case 'stepTwo' :
                this.setState({
                    step : 'stepTwo',
                    progression : '50%'
                });
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * Render
     * @return {JSX}
     */
    render() {

        const { step, progression } = this.state;

        switch (step) {
            case 'stepOne' :
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Header />

                            <WizardProgressBar progression={progression} stepOne="active" stepTwo="" />

                            <WizardStepOne handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} />

                        <Footer/>
                    </div>
                );
                break;
            case 'stepTwo' :
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Header />

                            <WizardProgressBar progression={progression} stepOne="done" stepTwo="active" />

                            <WizardStepTwo handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} />

                        <Footer/>
                    </div>
                );
                break;
        }
    }
}

export default Wizard;
```

**WizardStepOne**

```
export default class WizardStepOne extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

/**
 *
 * Render
 * @return {XML}
 */
render() {

    return(
        <div className="step-one">

            <h1>Step 1</h1>

            <WizardStepOneForm handleFormSubmit={this.props.handleFormSubmit} />

        </div>
    );
}
```

}

**WizardStepForm**

```
//... imports

@connect((store) => {
    return {

    };
})

export default class WizardStepOneForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            formData : {
                firstName : '',
                lastName  : '',
            },
            formErrors : {
                firstName : true,
                lastName  : true,
            },
            formErrorMessages : {
                firstName : 'some validation message',
                lastName  : 'some validation message',
            },
            formButtonEnabled : true,
        }

        this.handleSubmit          = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleFirstNameChange = this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleLastNameChange  = this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const stepOne = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stepOne'));
        if (stepOne !== null) {
            this.setState({
                formData : stepOne.formData,
                formErrors : stepOne.formErrors,
                formErrorMessages : stepOne.formErrorMessages,
            });
        }
    }

    handleFirstNameChange(e) {

        let formData          = this.state.formData;
        let formErrors        = this.state.formErrors;
        let formErrorMessages = this.state.formErrorMessages;

        formData.firstName    = e.target.value;

        if (!e.target.value) {
            formErrors.firstName = true;
        } else {
            formErrors.firstName = false;
        }
        this.setState({ formData : formData, formErrors : formErrors, formErrorMessages : formErrorMessages });
        localStorage.setItem('stepOne', JSON.stringify({ formData : formData, formErrors : formErrors, formErrorMessages : formErrorMessages }));
    }

    handleLastNameChange(e) {

        let formData          = this.state.formData;
        let formErrors        = this.state.formErrors;
        let formErrorMessages = this.state.formErrorMessages;

        formData.lastName     = e.target.value;

        if (!e.target.value) {
            formErrors.lastName = true;
        } else {
            formErrors.lastName = false;
        }
        this.setState({ formData : formData, formErrors : formErrors, formErrorMessages : formErrorMessages });
        localStorage.setItem('stepOne', JSON.stringify({ formData : formData, formErrors : formErrors, formErrorMessages : formErrorMessages }));
    }

    handleSubmitButton() {

    }

    handleSubmit(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.dispatch(addUser(this.state.formData));
    }

    /**
     *
     * Render
     * @return {XML}
     */
    render() {

        const firstNameError = this.state.formErrors.firstName ? 'error' : '';
        const lastNameError  = this.state.formErrors.lastName  ? 'error' : '';

        return(
            <form className="step-one-form">

                <div className="form-group right">

                    <div className="form-group__form-row">

                        <p className={classnames('col-2', firstNameError)}>
                            <label htmlFor="first_name">First name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="fist_name" autoComplete="off" onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange} value={this.state.formData.firstName} />
                            { firstNameError ? <FormElementErrorMessage message={this.state.formErrorMessages.firstName} /> : '' }
                        </p>

                        <p className={classnames('col-2', lastNameError)}>
                            <label htmlFor="last_name">Last name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="last_name" autoComplete="off" onChange={this.handleLastNameChange} value={this.state.formData.lastName} />
                            { lastNameError ? <FormElementErrorMessage message={this.state.formErrorMessages.lastName} /> : '' }
                        </p>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <button disabled={this.state.formButtonEnabled} onClick={this.props.handleFormSubmit} value="stepTwo">Next step</button>

            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: have you seen react-albus https://github.com/americanexpress/react-albus?

Comment: As far as I see, I would have still the same issue as my form validations would be done in the WizardStepOneForm component

Answer (score 1):

So, I found out it's probably more easy as I thought.

The form submit handler comes in the child component where the form is created. So we don't need to push it downwards from the parent as a prop.

As we will fire an action via the dispatcher when the form 'stepOne' is valid, we change the given state by the reducer. The store receives this state change, which has been appended via connect and the provider at the root of our app, the parent component will receive this state change and we can fire up the next wizard screen.